# Add the number of results in the result of the MongoDB query and put the results in an Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to add the number of results in the query response, and put the results in an array.
Can you please help me?

Here's my current MongoDB query: https://sourceb.in/kUL9kKDq2c.
Here is an example of an expected result (example with 500 results):

```
{
    response: [{
            _id: new ObjectId("627d7828990fff996621d5ea"),
            Name: 'test date',
            ActorId: 3,
            MovieId: 1,
            State: 100,
            ActorWatched: [110],
            RatedCount: 2,
            PublishedDate: 2022 - 05 - 12 T21: 21: 41.081 Z,
            AverageRating: 5,
            StarCoinsEarned: 100
        },
        {
            _id: new ObjectId("627d7828990fff996621d5ea"),
            Name: 'test date',
            ActorId: 3,
            MovieId: 2,
            State: 100,
            ActorWatched: [],
            RatedCount: 1,
            PublishedDate: 2022 - 05 - 12 T21: 21: 41.081 Z,
            AverageRating: 5,
            StarCoinsEarned: 100
        }],
    count: 500
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did... I wrote two separate aggregation pipelines one with skip and limit and one without skip and limit and executed both queries.

```
const responsePipeline = [stage1, stage2, skipStage, limitStage];
const countPipeline = [stage1, stage2, countStage];
const responseData = await yourModel.aggregate(responsePipeline);
const countData = await yourModel.aggregate(countPipeline);
```

Another way to get both response and count is by using "facet".

```
const responsePipeline = [stage1, stage2, skipStage, limitStage];
const countPipeline = [stage1, stage2, countStage];
const response = await yourModel.aggregate([
  {$facet:{"response":responsePipeline, "count":countPipeline}}
])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, this is what I'm doing now, but it doesn't work for me because 2 requests for the same thing take too long to be executed. How can I do this in the same query to increase performance?

Comment: @cypolo You could try using facet. Here's some reference. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/

Comment: @cypolo Please check the answer I have modified it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to check this out!